# Segue to another storyboard, but navigation controller is still visible

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have two storyboards:

1. Login / register purposes (without navigation view controller)
2. Main storyboard (with navigation view controller)

When I hit Logout button (navigation bar item) on Main storyboard I am redirected to Login storyboard, but still see the navigation bar. 
How can I do this segue an also leave navigation view controller, so that navigation bar will not be visible ?

Comment: Which type does the segue have?

Comment: If possible post a screenshot of your storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what you can do,

When you want to show a Login controller without navigation bar, use

```
        UIStoryboard * board = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        LoginCntrl * cntrl = [board instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginCntrl"];
        [self presentViewController:LoginCntrl animated:YES completion:^{

    }];
```

Here 'LoginCntrl' in `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method is, the identifier of the LoginCntrl specified in storyboard. 
Because `presentViewController` is not part of the navigation controller, this won't show you navigation bar at the top.

Answer (score 0):

On logout event, change the rootViewController of window,

1) Create object of appDelegate
2) Create object of LoginVC

```
appDelegateObject.window?.rootViewController = objectOfLoginViewController;
```